# How to force the same code-block font across platforms in .Rmd html output?

Tags: css, r, knitr, r-markdown

I've got a problem where my `l` and `1` look sufficiently similar as to confuse some beginners I've got reviewing my code.

I thought I could force the font to stay the same across platforms of my .html output by adding this to the css style sheet:

```
code {
  font-family: "Andale Mono", AndaleMono, monospace;
}
```

But I'm told it didn't succeed -- `l` and `1` are still hard to tell apart.

Is there any way to force the code to render identically across platforms?

Comment: Try adding `!important` at the end: `font-family: "Andale Mono", AndaleMono, monospace !important;`

Comment: I edited my comment. You could check online which fonts are available on all main platforms (Win, OSX, Linux).

Comment: It is not easy to succeed with local system fonts. You cannot guarantee a certain font exists on all platforms. The only solution is to use web fonts: https://fonts.google.com If your readers don't have access to internet, you can download web fonts and embed them in HTML (when `self_contained = TRUE`, this should be done automatically but Pandoc will download fonts every time you recompile, so I still recommend you to download fonts by yourself and use CSS).

Comment: As the others said. I just checked, and fun fact (from wiki): 
This typeface is no longer distributed with modern versions of Microsoft Windows (from Windows ME onwards), having been replaced by Lucida Console.

Comment: ugh what a terrible font Lucida Console is! http://www.ffonts.net/Lucida-Console.font

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use web fonts like Google fonts. Take [Source Code Pro](https://fonts.google.com/?category=Monospace&selection.family=Source+Code+Pro) for example. Google will tell you to add this to the `<head>` area of your HTML document:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code+Pro" rel="stylesheet">
```

and apply the CSS rule to `<code>` elements:

```
code {
  font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
}
```

For an R Markdown document, you can add things to `<head>` via the [`includes` option](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html#includes). For example, save the `<link>` code above in a file named `google-font.html` under the same directory as your Rmd file, save the CSS in `google-font.css`, and in the YAML of Rmd:

```
---
title: Your Document Title
output:
  html_document:
    includes:
      in_header: "google-font.html"
    css: "google-font.css"
---
```

Comment: it works! ninja stuff, thanks. think this is common enough to warrant a FR to have knitr handle this under the hood somehow?

Comment: The general rmarkdown documentation has already been there (same for Google fonts), and I think the problem is that many users do not know how to connect the dots (fonts -> CSS -> R Markdown -> HTML). You are welcome to contribute a short article to the rmarkdown documentation website!